# Terraform plan error while using terraform workspace as remote backend

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to upload my resource variables to terraform workspace using PowerShell script. In terraform plan task it is throwing the below error. When I verified the azure cli version it is running on 2.11. Any thoughts on this error. Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gz8Ip.png)

Comment: Please provide your PS and TF code, and don't use screenshots for code nor error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Please run:

```
az login
```

and then try again

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29475081)

Comment: I faced the similar issue and hence given the solution, not able to understand you comment thanks